# how do i display an index and a form on my show page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I have my User's (users model) show page display a list of the Serivces (another model) they are offering AND also a form where people can book Appointments (another model) for their Services?

It looks like I need to make the @services variable more flexible in my controller. But I'm not sure how. It seems like only one partial I am rendering is able to make use of it in my controller. Weird!

USERS CONTROLLER

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @appointment = Appointment.new
    @services = @user.services.collect {|service| [ service.id, service.title, service.description, service.length, service.user_id] }
  end

end
```

USERS/SHOW.HTML.ERB:
LIST OF SERVICES PARTIAL: <% render 'shared/services_list' %>

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Start time</th>
      <th>End time</th>
      <th>Note</th>
      <th>Service</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @appointments.each do |appointment| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= appointment.start_time %></td>
        <td><%= appointment.end_time %></td>
        <td><%= appointment.note %></td>
        <td><%= appointment.service.title %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', appointment %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_appointment_path(appointment) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', appointment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

USERS/SHOW.HTML.ERB:
APPOINTMENTS FORM PARTIAL: <%= render 'appointments/form' %>

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Length</th>
      <th>User</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @services.each do |service| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= service.title %></td>
        <td><%= service.description %></td>
        <td><%= service.length %></td>
        <td><%= service.user.email %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', service %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_service_path(service) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', service, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

ERROR:
NoMethodError in Users#show
undefined method `title' for [1, "exmaple title", "example description", 90, 1]:Array

Line 15 is highlighted -> <%= service.title %>

```
<tbody>
       <% @services.each do |service| %>
         <tr>
           <td><%= service.title %></td>
           <td><%= service.description %></td>
           <td><%= service.length %></td>
           <td><%= service.user.email %></td>
```

Thanks!

Comment: take a look at the documentation of the collect method. you return an array of values for each service and not the service object. So naturally, there is no method named 'title' on the returned service array

Comment: thanks @peshkira - can you give me an example of how that would look? -- to call the object and the array? (because I need them both.)

Comment: okay. nevermind. thank you. I got it. I'll post the full answer once I complete my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. @peshkira was right. I neeeded to call the object.

So I added this line to my controller `@services_list = @user.services.collect` so I could create a list in the style of an 'index'.

My full controller looks like this.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @appointment = Appointment.new
    @services = @user.services.collect {|service| [ service.title, service.id] }
    @services_list = @user.services.collect
  end

end
```

That will supply functionality for a nested form(A Service & an Appointment for that Service) and also pull the data for a list of Services.